# How to make changes to the HTML in the homepage of a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a theme called Starkit, I searched for index.html in the theme editor but didn't find it, instead I found index.php file that only has these lines of code:

```
<?php 
/**
Template Name: Default homepage
*/
?>
<?php 
    get_header();
    do_action( 'startkit_sections', false );
    get_template_part('sections/startkit','blog');
    get_footer();
?>
```

I want to make some changes in HTML but I have no idea where I can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in wordpress there is no .html files ... you will find all the html inside .php files next to php blocks..

just like this :

```
<div>
<?php echo 'hey mohammed';
</div>
```

which will print out the sentence : 'hey mohamed' inside a  tag ...

and some times you will find html written INSIDE php blocks ..
just like this :

```
<?php echo '<div>hey mohammed</div>'; ?>
```

which does the same as the first block

---

**so how does you deal with wordpress files and edit its html !?**

in wordpress there is a [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) that have to be used ...

example :

the header.php contains something like this (with alot of php block inside it) [take a look at header.php](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-headerphp-what-needs-to-go-in-it-and-what-doesnt--wp-24923) :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>something</title>   
</head>
<body>
```

and footer.php will contains something like this :

```
</body>
</html>
```

---

**so now after we understand how does WordPress work :**
i can explain your code:

1. [get_header()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) is used to include the header.php file.
2. [get_footer()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/) is used to include the footer.php file.
3. [do_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/) creates something called hooks that can be executed in another place
4. [get_template_part('sections/startkit','blog')](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) is used to include a file called startkit-blog.php inside a folder called "sections".

**Notice** : most of the HTML you want to edit does exists inside the sections/startkit-blog.php file...

---